# Get folder from a path and open files in that folder

Tags: vb.net

Im making a VB.Net application that will be used to open Visual Studio projects faster. I added the projects into a `ComboBox` and i want to use a button to open the SLN file. Here is my code so far.

```
     Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments + "\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\")
        Dim Folders As String = dir.Split("Projects\")(1)
        Dim Project As String = Folders.Split("\")(1)
        CBProjects.Items.Add(Project)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BTNOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNOpen.Click

End Sub
```

So it get the Folders and splits them so it only shows the Project name. For some reason it is getting a blank folder for one of my projects. Also now that i split it how do i get the full path for the selected folder so i can open it using `System.IO.File.Open()` Thanks in advance!
**EDIT:** It is giving a empty folder because it is spliting it at the P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your code is, as you say, that the string is split on "P". This is because the [**`String.Split(Char())` overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) that you're using takes **an array of chars** as argument, which is what a string essentially is. The string will be split when any of those characters are found.

Instead you should use the [**`String.Split(String(), StringSplitOptions)` overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx), which takes **an array of strings**.

```
Dim Project As String = dir.Split(New String() {"Projects\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1)
```

There is however two things you can improve here:

1. Instead of manually concatenating two strings into a path use [**`Path.Combine()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct it. This includes error checking and ensures that the path is constructed properly.
2. Instead of splitting the strings use [**`Path.GetFileName()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the name of the project directory.

The resulting code is:

```
For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects"))
    Dim Project As String = Path.GetFileName(dir)
    CBProjects.Items.Add(Project)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly was i was looking for!

Comment: Just did it! Thanks again!

Comment: One more question if you dont mind: On the button i put `Process.start(Project + "\" + CBProject.SelectedItem + ".sln")` for some reason it says it cant find the file. I would think it would because it would be like Project1\Project1.sln

Comment: @JakeTous : Correct. Though why are you still using ordinary string concatenation? ;) `Path.Combine()` is the recommended way to construct paths. In your case just prepend the document directory again: `Process.Start(Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", CBProject.SelectedItem.ToString(), CBProject.SelectedItem.ToString() & ".sln"))` (or see Andrew's solution below).

Answer (score 1):

Add a new class for your custom ComboItem

```
Public Class ProjectComboItem
    Public Display As String
    Public ProjectPath As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Display
    End Function
End Class
```

Load items into your ComboBox:

```
Private Sub loadProjectComboBox()

    ProjectComboBox.Items.Clear()

    Dim projectParent As String = "<yourpath>\Visual Studio 2017\Projects"
    Dim paths() As String = Directory.GetFiles(projectParent, "*.sln", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each path As String In paths
        Dim cmbItem As New ProjectComboItem
        Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(path)
        cmbItem.Display = fi.Name
        cmbItem.ProjectPath = fi.FullName
        ProjectComboBox.Items.Add(cmbItem)
    Next

End Sub
```

Get the full path back when you need it:

```
Private Sub OpenButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenButton.Click
    Try
        If Not ProjectComboBox.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            Dim cmbItem As ProjectComboItem = DirectCast(ProjectComboBox.SelectedItem, ProjectComboItem)
            Process.Start(cmbItem.ProjectPath)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```